# Contiki OS loops too fast to print result?

Tags: c, loops, contiki

In one of my Contiki applications I am calling a certain function (f) from a PROCESS (P). The 'printf' in (P) displays the result correctly when there is atleast one 'printf' in the loop residing in (f). However, when there is no 'printf's in that same loop, the result is blank. 
   Can anyone please help me understand why delaying the loop with printf call is displaying the result and why it doesn't display without this particular call.

```
    **CODE:**
    function_f(...){
    ....
    ....
    char res1[LEN];
    ....
     for(i=LEN-1;i>1;i--){   
           ....addition operations...

           if(temp > 9 && (i-1) > 0){                                       

               ...division operation...
               ...addition and remainder operation...

           }else{

               ....addition....
               ....assignment.... 

           }

       }
      return res1
    }


PROCESS_THREAD(...){
....
    **printf**("\nResult: %s", function_f(...));
....
}
```

Thank you,
Avijit

Comment: please post a minimal code, that cleanly compiles, and demonstrates the problem.  at the very least, post the related printf() statements

Comment: The the printf() format string end with `\n`?   have you tried using 'fflush(stdout)`?   most likely is the printf() output doesn't show because of the system buffering of output.

Comment: I don't think fflush stdout is working for embedded systems like sensor nodes

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to keep using a pointer to `res1` outside the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding this line: return res1 the res1 will be a pointer to an array that is located on the stack. When the function exits, the values on the stack 'go out of scope' resulting in undefined behaviour if the pointer res1 is de-referenced. One possible fix:

```
char * res1 = NULL; 
res1 = malloc(LEN); 
if(NULL == res1) 
{ // handle error } 
else ....
```

Of course, then the caller needs to pass res1 to free()

Since the posted code (and presumably your actual code) shows undefined behaviour, any re-arrangment of the code can/will result in different effects. In your case, adding/removing a call to printf() is showing the observed effects.